# Scraping cdkeys[dot]com

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get price changes for a certain product but I'm getting mixed results with either Selenium or Beautifulsoup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www[.]cdkeys.com[/]playstation-network-psn[/]playstation-plus[/]1-year-playstation-plus-membership-ps3-ps4-ps-vita-digital-code')
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="price"]')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
price = soup.find_all('span',{'class':['price']})
```

**search** returns an object of some sort but with an empty text property.

**price** gets a few dozens of results back including the one I'm interested in. I believe it's behind some sort of an API but I was not able to find it using Dev Tools sorted by XHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to combine beautiful soup and selenium in
that situation, one of them enough to do the whole job.

I would choose beautifulSoup (with requests)
The reason for that -
this scraping does not require javascript
and beautifulSoup is much lighter in terms of performance than selenium.

About the scraping method -
You got dozens of results because you searched the element only by  his class name, and there's many elements in that name.
one of the solutions is to combine multiple
attributes to find the   correct element as I did in the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
url = "https://www.cdkeys.com/playstation-network-psn/playstation-plus/1-year-playstation-plus-membership-ps3-ps4-ps-vita-digital-code?mw_aref=xcalibur"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.text, features='html.parser')
product_main = soup.find('div', {'class': 'product-info-main'})
product_price = product_main.find('span', {'data-price-type': 'finalPrice', 'class': 'price-wrapper'})
print(product_price.text)
```

Comment: That hit the spot. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a wait before getting element with Selenium to let the element fully loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://www[.]cdkeys.com[/]playstation-network-psn[/]playstation-plus[/]1-year-playstation-plus-membership-ps3-ps4-ps-vita-digital-code')
search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/span[@class="price"]')))
time.sleep(0.5)
prices_in_usd = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='price' and contains(text(),'$')]")


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
price = soup.find_all('span',{'class':['price']})
```

And if you want to get the element text don't forget to extract that text

```
search_text = search.text
```

Comment: I think you're missing the declaration for "wait". But even after adding "wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)" it just times out and errors.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my error. I added the wait declaration. Also changed condition from visibility to existence. Now this should work. If still not - your locator is wrong or there is an iframe there.

Comment: UPD! There are 42 price elements there. At least the first 2 are not visible. So it's correct that visibility condition is failed.

Comment: Ah, do you have any idea how can I get just the $ one? It's all in Euros for some reason...

Comment: @JustAGuy maybe. but why did you remove the answer acceptance?

Comment: Because unfortunately that does not fully answer the question just yet. I mean, it gets me 42 options but they are all scrambled.

Comment: In order to get elements with `$` texts only I added additional code line. Also added short sleep to make sure all the relevant elements are fully loaded. Let me know if now this is what you are asked about